# How add top padding in drawer icon?

Tags: html, css, material-design

[image: img]

I am using material design lite css..

In their website this code working good..

I mean that drawer icon is showing at the middle.

```
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<!-- Material Design icon font -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

So can anyone help me?

It's working fine in CODE SNIPPET :(

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
       <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Always shows a header, even in smaller screens. -->
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <!-- Title -->
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
          <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
          <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
          <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show any relevant HTML.

Comment: https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section @SumnerEvans .. Same problem with all layout there :(

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40326077/edit) your question and use the code block feature to add your HTML to the post.

Comment: added but it's working fine in code snippet :(

Comment: But i tried to add that code in every rowser same problem at different size

Comment: Can u plz try this code on your browser ? @SumnerEvans

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<!doctype html>` at the very start of the html code (at the first line, before `<html>`) to tell the browser your page is using HTML5.

Comment: Thanx but it's not the soultion for my problem

Comment: Did you try it?